# Are all Inconsequentia quests solvable?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Is it 100% possible to complete every quest received from Statue of Inconsequentia?

I just played the game for few days so far and I am now in level 4, but already had around 2-3 quests that I found impossible to complete. My problem is mostly connected with quests that require finding specific items & using them on pillar of eyes (can't find item) or eliminating members of Dredmor's cohort (where are the mobs, how to tell if they are cohort mobs?). I tried to explore whole level carefully, killing every monster encountered, in vain. There is no location marked on the minimap (as it is in most cases when some boss must be brought down or specific item recovered).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten bugged requests from Inconsequentia before - usually the worst ones are the ones that make you kill a certain group of enemies.  If I've already explored most of the map, these quests tend not to spawn for me.  [Comments on recent patch notes](http://www.gaslampgames.com/2011/12/22/bride-of-the-scorpion-diggle/#comments) on the Gaslamp Blog seem to indicate I'm not the only one.  Other bugs seem to surround Uber Chests.

You can tell if you're killing the right enemies because every time one dies, there will be a little message in the log in the upper left corner telling you how many of that group of enemies still remain.

Comment: Ahh, yes I remember noticing this 'x monsters left' in message log, and indeed the dev team admitted some problems exist in current version (1.0.9 - http://www.gaslampgames.com/2011/12/28/post-holiday-update/). So I guess we will have to wait until the guys will release another patch.

Comment: OK the Revision B of 1.0.9 patch was released on Steam, fixing some of the bugs introduced in the original version. I already played a couple of games and did not find a single quest unsolvable, so I believe by design it is possible to complete all quests, and my problem was a bug of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I got quests that I had problems solving myself, items will mostly be dropped by some mob that is spawned after accepting the quests. I never got a quest item from a crate or the like.

Note also that the quest mob may spawn in an area already discovered, but it will always spawn on the level that the quest is given on.

> The items and/or monsters that are the targets of quests do not appear on the map until the quest is accepted, so they may appear in areas already explored. The object of each quest will be located on the same dungeon level as the Statue of Inconsequentia that gave it.

(from http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Quests)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the case when the quest item was marked on the minimap right after accepting the quest, it was just lying around in area I already explored earlier (just appeared out of nowhere). I mostly have the problem with this cohort stuff or quest items not lying anywhere on the level (no mark on minimap) - could it be I sold the quest item to the checkered-suit shopkeeper by mistake? No way to buy it back then I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure you can sell quest items, but I'd have to test that to be sure. In that case the quest would be broken, though.